# Reactor, how to debug an OverflowException?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

I'm trying to find a way to understand/debug why I randomly have that stacktrace :

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests
at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithOverflow(Exceptions.java:215)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.emit(FluxBufferPredicate.java:292)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.onNextNewBuffer(FluxBufferPredicate.java:251)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.tryOnNext(FluxBufferPredicate.java:205)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.onNext(FluxBufferPredicate.java:180)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:201)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:271)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:803)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:232)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:190)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1444)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1318)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:128)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61)
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6873)
```

Does it means that the producer is faster than the consumer ? My pattern is probably not standard and looks like the following (simplified here):

```
Flux<Pair<Person, String>> auto = getPersons() // REST GET endpoint
        .map(p -> {
            // In my real-life example, the operation done here is quiet expensive.
            Person newP = new Person(p.name, p.age + 10);
            return new Pair<>(newP, "The new age of " + newP.name + " is now " + newP.age);
        })
        .publish()
        .autoConnect(2);

    Flux<Person> personsToSave = auto.map(e -> e.first);
    Flux<String> auditToSave = auto.map(e -> e.second);

    Mono.when(
            savePersons(personsToSave), // REST POST endpoint
            saveAudit(auditToSave))     // REST POST endpoint
        .doOnError(e -> System.err.println(e.getMessage()))
        .block();
```

The Hooks.onOperatorDebug(), or log() does not help me a lot. I don't have the problem if I remove the publish() and only save the persons OR the audit.

Can someone give me how to investigate more precisely ? (or an idea to solve the issue)
Reactor 3.1.6

Comment: it looks like the error originates in the part you left out, from a `windowUntil` or `windowWhile`... Have you also tried upgrading to the latest 3.1.10.RELEASE by any chance?

Comment: Indeed, I have a windowUntil in the stack. I'm using spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE (importing Bismuth-SR8). I will try to build a 'small' example to reproduce that behavior. Actually I have several issues that I 'solved' by disabling the connection pool in the HttpClientOption and changing the MediaType from APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON to TEXT_EVENT_STREAM.